# Creating a Secure Websocket (wss) Server in Java

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

**My main objective is to maintain TLS on a secure website**. I'm currently running `ws` on an `https` site, the "SSL Lock" in Chrome is appearing red/broken because I am using a non-authenticated source from an `https` website. I need to secure the WebSocket so that the SSL Lock is preserved.

I've been searching the web for an example of how to implement `wss` in Java (server) and JavaScript (client), but I can't seem to find anything that I can use. I've seen a few examples of how create an SSL Server (I do have the necessary certificates for a TLS/SSL connection), but I'm not sure how to translate this to `wss`.

If anyone could provide an example on how to use `wss` from Java, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?  If you are using a cert that does not link back to a CA trusted by your client platform you'll never get the green happiness in the browser bar no matter what framework/lib you use to implement your WebSocket with.

Answer (score 1):

A secure websocket can use a standard SSL certificate for a web server.  You could do this in, for example, Tomcat or use Apache with mod_proxy_wstunnel between the browser and you Java server.

Comment: This seems to be the direction I want to go in. Do you have any resources for mod_proxy_wstunnel? I'm new to Apache =/

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the docs - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html - to get an idea of how to get started.  I'd personally start without SSL and then move to get a real SSL certificate for your Apache instance.  You'll setup will be browser --> Apache --> Tomcat (or other server).

Comment: I already checked out the docs, but I couldn't get much from them. I tried `sudo yum install mod_proxy_wstunnel` in the Amazon EC2 instance, but it has no packages to install. I already have SSL set up for normal HTTPS, I just need it to apply for WebSockets, too. To my knowledge, I need the package before I can even continue, right?

Comment: So after a little digging the first issue is that Amazon EC2's ("Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03.0") come with Apache 2.2 and mod_proxy_wstunnel is an Apache 2.4 thing.  It might be easier to forget Apache and do this in Tomcat - it sounds like you've already got that working with a self-signed certificate.  Tomcat has docs on this (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) that could help too.  Otherwise you'll need to move to the Ubuntu EC2 AMI which does have Apache 2.4.

Comment: Could I `sudo yum install httpd24` to get Apache 2.4 on the EC2 box and then get mod_proxy_wstunnel, or would this ruin all the configs and SSL?

Comment: I upgraded to Apache2.4 so I have the mod_proxy_wstunnel module. Which config files should I edit to get SSL to work on the WebSockets? I feel like I almost have the solution and I would really appreciate your help on finishing this.